# Remove class from element in a parent node with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove the class from my `.hide` elements by clicking on a link. The div that needs to be affect are only the one in the parent `<div class="row">`.

This is what I've tried - Note, that I've more than one block like this.

```js
$('a[data-action="show-more"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.row').each('.hide').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
    <div class="col-lg-4 hide"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 hide"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 hide"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
    <a href="#" data-action="show-more">Remove hide class</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `find` instead of `each`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey More a close as typo-type situation after your comment than a dupe

Comment: @mplungjan whichever. Dupe means a gold badge could close it faster.

Comment: Yeah but op already used the correct method to remove the class so it’s your `find` that’s the true answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close.  [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is for creating a callback function that will iterate over the results.  To simply find matching descendants and provide the results to the next chained jQuery function, use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('.hide').removeClass('hide');
```

Comment: A comment and vote to close would have done it